# Mail is not working in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am using below code to send email in yii2:

In config/main.php

```
return [
    'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail'
        ],
    ],
];
```

In my controller:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact', [
                        'name' => 'Dan Drown',
                        'address' => '111 Highway 50, CA'])
                ->setFrom('dandrown@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('dandrown@gmail.com')
                ->setSubject('Re: Hello word')
                ->send();
```

But I didn't get any mail in mail dandrown@gmail.com. And I don't know why? What's the issue?

Comment: Does your server support mailing? Can you create a new php file to test the mail() function? Some hosts don't allow mailing, especially cloud hosts like Heroku, at least not without additional steps. If it's a tradition server, it should be able to mail.

Comment: Did you check your spam list?

Comment: Yes, I checked, but it wasn't any mail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of properly configured mailer:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
    ],
],
```

You can read more here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html

Comment: Thank you! But when I use gmail, it is limited if you send greater than 20 mails. I want to use default mail of mail server. Can you give me other idea, can't you?